# Multiple concurrent $.post causing blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app where multiple concurrent ajax requests are sent out to my nodeJS backend server. The calls are sent out in rapid succession and immediately sent out again after data is received.

I don't mean all of JS is being blocked, please view the screenshot (bottom right corner) to see what I'm referring to.

[image]

Can someone please explain to me what this blocking is and if there is anyway around it?

Comment: There's a limit to how many concurrent connections the browser will allow per origin. Are you sure you have to send all of those in separate HTTP requests? If so, you should do them through different sub-domains.

Answer (score 1):

There is a  browser connection limit, but most modern browsers are [6+ concurrent connections,](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network) it looks like it is being blocked on the server side.  Is this request fairly CPU intensive?  If it is, Node might be holding up the request as it is single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is probably limiting the number of simultaneous connections to the server.

PS.

> It is, however, considered poor etiquette to make too many connections to a server and may lead to you being banned from that server. Anything above 10 is excessive. 
>  -  *mozillaZine : [Network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server)* -

Comment: I'm using Chrome, is there a way to un-limit the amount of connections? The server I am making connections to is my own, which then makes an eBay API call. My developer API key is specially licensed by eBay to make up to 20 million calls per day.